# Fill area between images with color - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a series of images and I need to color the area between them with color by taking pixel values from the images or increase the width of the images along Z-axis so that when I remove the spacing between the images I will be able to see a 3D model stacked with images.

For simplicity, I used dummy images, in reality, I have to work with many complex images without clean edges.

would appreciate any help or even new approach that maybe I need to take. I have attached an image to show you how it looks.

[image]

```html
<div class="container">
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.3/dat.gui.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
<script>

 function instructions(){
  this.Rotate = 'Left Mouse Click';
  this.Pan = 'Right Mouse Click';
  this.Zoom = 'Scroll Mouse';
 }

 function buildGui() {
  if (gui) {
    gui.destroy();
    gui = null;
  }

  gui = new dat.GUI( );
  var text = new instructions();
  gui.add(text, 'Rotate');
  gui.add(text, 'Pan');
  gui.add(text, 'Zoom');
  folderGlobal = gui.addFolder( 'Clipping' ),
  propsGlobalX = {
   get 'Enable Clipping'() { return renderer.clippingPlanes !== Empty; },
   set 'Enable Clipping'( v  ) {
     renderer.clippingPlanes = v ? globalPlanes : Empty; },
   get 'X-Plane'() { return xPlane.constant; },
   set 'X-Plane'( v ) { xPlane.constant = v; },
  };
  propsGlobalY = {

   get 'Y-Plane'() { return yPlane.constant; },
   set 'Y-Plane'( v ) { yPlane.constant = v; },
  };
  propsGlobalZ = {

   get 'Z-Plane'() { return zPlane.constant; },
   set 'Z-Plane'( v ) { zPlane.constant = v; },
  };
  propsGlobalD = {

   get 'D-Plane'() { return dPlane.constant; },
   set 'D-Plane'( v ) { dPlane.constant = v; },
  };

  folderGlobal.add( propsGlobalX, 'Enable Clipping' );
  folderGlobal.add( propsGlobalX, 'X-Plane', -200, 200);
  folderGlobal.add( propsGlobalY, 'Y-Plane', -200, 200 );
  folderGlobal.add( propsGlobalZ, 'Z-Plane', -200, 200 );
  folderGlobal.add( propsGlobalD, 'D-Plane', -200, 200 );

  startTime = Date.now();

  guiViews = gui.addFolder('Views');
  guiViews.add( guiConfig, 'home_view' );
  guiViews.add( guiConfig, 'top_view' );
  guiViews.add( guiConfig, 'side_view' );

  guiExtras = gui.addFolder('View Options');
  guiExtras.open();

  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'Zoom', 0.5, 5 ).step(.1).onFinishChange( function() {
   ZoomView ( guiConfig.Zoom );
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'Opacity', 0, 1.0 ).step(.1).onFinishChange( function() {
   changeOpacity( guiConfig.Opacity );
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'Spacing', 0, 10 ).step(1).onFinishChange( function() {
   changeSpacing( guiConfig.Spacing );
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'ShowPlane', ).onChange( togglePlane );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'ShowBoundary' ).onChange( toggleBoundary );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'ShowAxes' ).onChange( toggleAxis );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'ShowMarker', true ).onChange( toggleMarker );

  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'markerX', -100, 100 ).onChange( function() {
   if (box) { box.position.x = guiConfig.markerX; }
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'markerY', -100, 100 ).onChange( function() {
   if (box) { box.position.y = guiConfig.markerY; }
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'markerZ', -100, 100 ).onChange( function() {
   if (box) { box.position.z = guiConfig.markerZ; }
  } );

  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'markerScaleX', 0, 5 ).onChange( function() {
   if (box) { box.scale.x = guiConfig.markerScaleX; }
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'markerScaleY', 0, 5 ).onChange( function() {
   if (box) { box.scale.y = guiConfig.markerScaleY; }
  } );
  guiExtras.add( guiConfig, 'markerScaleZ', 0, 5 ).onChange( function() {
   if (box) { box.scale.z = guiConfig.markerScaleZ; }
  } );
 }

 function changeOpacity(opacity){
  var all_slides = scene.children[1].children;
  for ( var i = 0; i <= all_slides.length - 1 ; i++ ) {
   all_slides[i].material.opacity = opacity;
  }
  guiConfig.Opacity = opacity;
 }

 function changeSpacing(spacing){
  guiConfig.Spacing = spacing;
  visualisationApp.buildVisualization();
 }

 function ZoomView( y ) {
  camera.zoom = y;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 }

 function RotateView( y ) {
  var elm = controls.domElement, wiw = 0.5 * window.innerWidth, wih = 0.5 * window.innerHeight;
  mouseEvent(elm, "mousedown", 0, wiw, wih);
  mouseEvent(elm, "mousemove", 0, wiw - y, wih);
  mouseEvent(elm, "mouseup");
 }

 function panView( x, y ) {
  var elm = controls.domElement,  wiw = 0.5 * window.innerWidth, wih = 0.5 * window.innerHeight;
  mouseEvent( elm, "mousedown", 2, wiw, wih );
  mouseEvent( elm, "mousemove", 2, wiw + x, wih - y );
  mouseEvent( elm, "mouseup", 2);
  camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);
  camera.position.set(200, 100, 250);
 }

 function togglePlane() {
  if ( guiConfig.planeVisible === false) {
   if ( plane ) { plane.visible = false; }
  } else if ( plane ) {
   plane.visible = true;
  } else {
   geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 500, 0.1, 500, 10, 10, 10);
   material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { wireframe: true } );
   plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
   plane.position.set(0, slides.meshY, 0);
   scene.add( plane );
  }
 }
 function toggleAxis() {
  if ( guiConfig.axisVisible === false) {
   if ( axis ) { axis.visible = false; }
  } else if ( axis ) {
   axis.visible = true;
  } else {
   axis = new THREE.AxisHelper( 100 );
   scene.add( axis );
  }
 }

 function toggleBoundary() {
  if ( guiConfig.boundaryVisible === false) {
   if ( boundary ) { boundary.visible = false; }
  } else if (boundary) {
   boundary.visible = true;
  } else {
   geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1);
   material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { wireframe: true } );
   boundary = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
   boundary.rotation.x = slides.angle;
   boundary.position.set(0, slides.startY + 0.5 * (slides.count * guiConfig.Spacing), slides.startZ + 0.5 * slides.count * slides.deltaZ);
   scene.add( boundary );
  }
 }

 function toggleMarker() {
  if ( guiConfig.markerVisible === false) {
   if ( box ) { box.visible = false; }
  } else if (box) {
   box.visible = true;
  } else {
   geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50);
   material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( { wireframe: true } );
   box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
   scene.add( box );
  }
 }

 function toggleSplash() {
  if ( splash.style.display === 'block' ) {
   splash.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
   splash.style.display = 'block';
  }
 };

 function mouseEvent(element, type, button, cx, cy ) {
  var evt,
  e = {
   bubbles: true, cancelable: (type !== "mousemove"), view: window, detail: 0,
   screenX: 0, screenY: 0, clientX: cx, clientY: cy,
   ctrlKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false, metaKey: false,
   button: button, relatedTarget: undefined
  };
  button = button || 0;
  cx = cx || 0;
  cy = cy || 0;
  evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
  evt.initMouseEvent(type, e.bubbles, e.cancelable, e.view, e.detail,
  e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY,
  e.ctrlKey, e.altKey, e.shiftKey, e.metaKey,
  e.button, document.body.parentNode);
  element.dispatchEvent(evt);
  return evt;
 }

 function init() {

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: 1, antialias: true, clearColor: 0xffffff } );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  $('.container').append( renderer.domElement );

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000 );
  camera.position.set( 200, 100, 250 );
  scene.add( camera );

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  controls.maxDistance = 800;


   xPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( - 1, 0, 0 ), 200 );
   yPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, -1, 0 ), 200 );
   zPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 ), 200 );
   dPlane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( -1, -1, 0 ), 200 );

   globalPlanes = [ xPlane, yPlane, zPlane, dPlane ],
  Empty = Object.freeze( [] );
  renderer.clippingPlanes = Empty; // GUI sets it to globalPlanes
  raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

  guiConfig.scansFinish = slides.count;
  visualisationApp.buildVisualization();
  buildGui();
    }

    function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
 }

    function render() {
  controls.update( clock.getDelta() );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }

 function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

  var mouse = { x: -1, y: -1 };
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
   if ( guiConfig.highlighting && intersected !== intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
    if ( intersected ) { intersected.material.opacity = guiConfig.Opacity; }
    intersected = intersects[ 0 ].object;
    slidesGroup.current = slidesGroup.children.indexOf(intersected);
   }
  } else {
   if (intersected) { intersected.material.opacity = guiConfig.Opacity; }
   intersected = null;
  }
  mouseMove = true;
 }

 var visualisationApp = visualisationApp || {};

 visualisationApp.buildVisualization = function() {
  if ( slidesGroup ) { scene.remove( slidesGroup ); }
  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 200, 200, 1, 1);
  slidesGroup = new THREE.Group();
  slidesGroup.current = 0;
  var image_array = ["https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/pathology-imageviewer/newfilter03.png"];



  for ( var i = 0; i <= image_array.length - 1; i++ ) {
   map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image_array[i]);
   map.minFilter = map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
   material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: map, opacity: guiConfig.Opacity, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true, wireframe: false, clipShadows: true} );
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
   mesh.rotation.x = slides.angle;
   mesh.position.set(0, slides.startY + (i * guiConfig.Spacing) - (guiConfig.Spacing*image_array.length), slides.startZ + i * slides.deltaZ);
   slidesGroup.add( mesh );

  }
  scene.add( slidesGroup );
 };

 var gui, guiView, guiFiles, guiViews, guiScans, guiCamera, guiExtras, guiHelp;
 var guiConfig = {
  Zoom: 0.5,
  Rotate: 1.0,
  Vertical: 1.0,
  Horizontal: 1.0,
  Opacity: 0.8,
  Spacing: 1,

  home_view: function() {
   controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
   camera.up.set(0, 1, 0);
   camera.position.set(200, 100, 250);
  },
  top_view: function() {
   controls.target.set(0,0,0);
   camera.up.set(0,1,0);
   camera.position.set(0, 200, 0);
  },
  side_view: function() {
   camera.up.set(0,1,0);
   controls.target.set(0,0,0);
   camera.position.set(200, 5, 0);
  },
  highlighting: true,
  cameraCutoffNear: 1,
  cameraCutoffFar: 500,
  ShowPlane: false,
  ShowBoundary: false,
  ShowAxes: false,
  ShowMarker: false,
  markerX: 0,
  markerY: 0,
  markerZ: 0,
  markerScaleX: 0,
  markerScaleY: 0,
  markerScaleZ: 0,
 };

 //3d visualisation

 var scene, camera, controls, light, stats, renderer;
 var geometry, map, material, mesh;

 var clock = new THREE.Clock();
 var projector;
 var intersected;
 var mouseMove;
 var raycaster;
 var slidesGroup, plane, boundary, axis, box;


 //slides array for an actual series of images to test

 var slides =  {
  count: 26,
  angle: 1.5708,
  startY: 40,
  startZ: 0,
  deltaZ: 0,
  meshY: -50
 };

 init();
 animate();
</script>
```

Comment: What should the final result look like?

Comment: Seems you're looking for a mesh with a cylinder geometry and a material with `side: THREE.BackSide`.

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica The final result should be a 3D model. So that when I apply clipping I should be able to see the insides of the model. Is there any other way I can achieve is other than trying to apply color between the images?

Comment: @JDBstillremembersMonica I tried to see if I can somehow increase the thickness of the images and remove spacing between the images to achieve a 3D model but I couldn't do that too.